# Is inpolite to say "check this out"?

Tags: idioms, sentence-usage, politeness

Is there any problem to say *check this out* in a corporate environment in general situations?

E.g: I am writing an email to a supplier to verify an issue, sending a ticket to IT support or even talking wit my boss about some problem.

If so, what can I say instead?

Comment: *Check this out* has several different meanings: to invite someone to experience something, to instruct someone to inspect or investigate something, or to instruct someone to reserve something, to start. It is not "impolite" in and of itself, but I personally would consider it too informal to use with strangers or superiors. We need more context to provide a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in saying '[check this out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/check-sth-out)'. Unless the thing one is referring to, is wrong to refer to that way, like 'a person'.

However, formally you could use words like: "examine, go through, assess, weigh up, analyse, evaluate".

Comment: In my case I referring to a situation, so its okay.

Comment: @gmsantos Yes, referring to a situation should be fine.